# In java how to pass parameter to a method with @scheduled?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

Now I have a scheduled method:

```
@Scheduled(corn = "0 0 0 * * *")
public void method(){
  // do something;
}
```

Now I wish to pass a parameter (boolean save) to the method. Here `save =true` while the method is called scheduled, and `save = false` while the method is called in another way, which is like:

```
@Scheduled(corn = "0 0 0 * * *")
public void method(boolean save){
  // do something;
}
```

But it returns an error:

> Only no-arg methods may be annotated with @Scheduled

So How can I achieve this?

Comment: a wrapper class enclosing functionality

Comment: @Scheduled can be applied if a method is returning void and takes no argument. If you need to pass argument create a new method with argument and call your existing method within that.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I wish to pass a parameter (boolean save) to method. Here save =
> true while the method is called scheduled, and save = false while the
> method is called in other way

You can't use parameters in a sheduled method. What you could do is overload your method like this:

```
@Scheduled(corn = "0 0 0 * * *")
public void method(){
  // do something;
}

public void method(boolean save){
  if (save) {
     method();
     return;
  }
  // do something else;
}
```

This way when you call `method(false)`, your second method will be called, if you call `method(true)` your first method will be executed inside of your second method while still making your first method available for sheduling.

Answer (score 1):

You can get both scheduled and manual call way of tasks by using [Elastic-job](https://github.com/apache/shardingsphere-elasticjob).It provides a triger api to call task manual.

If you need this `save` flag to do someting different,I think you should pull away logic here and provide it for different entrance.
Like this

```
public void doSomething(boolean flag) {
  // do something;
}

@Scheduled(corn = "0 0 0 * * *")
public void method(){
  doSomething(true);
}

@RequestMapping("/xxx")
public void method(){
  doSomething(false);
}
```